# sass error when trying to run gulp local webserver

Tags: sass, gulp, gulp-sass

I have node.js and gulp.js installed, npm install works fine but then when I try to run the gulp local webserver it stops at 'sass' with the error messages below.

I have tried uninstalling node.js and gulp.js as well as wiping out the node_modules folder and running npm install again but no luck yet. Any suggestions?

```
[09:50:25] Starting 'generate-sass-index'...
[09:50:26] Finished 'generate-sass-index' after 68 ms
[09:50:26] Starting 'sass'...
[09:50:26] SOURCE CODE ERROR
[09:50:26] formatted Error: You may not @extend an outer selector from within @media.
   You may only @extend selectors within the same directive.
   From "@extend .col-md-6" on line 134 of LocalDistribution/sass/ItemDetails/_item-details.scss
    on line 11 of LocalDistribution/sass/twitter-bootstrap-sass/mixins/_grid-framework.scss
>>
[09:50:26] message LocalDistribution\sass\twitter-bootstrap-sass\mixins\_grid-framework.scss
Error: You may not @extend an outer selector from within @media.
   You may only @extend selectors within the same directive.
   From "@extend .col-md-6" on line 134 of    LocalDistribution/sass/ItemDetails/_item-details.scss
    on line 11 of LocalDistribution/sass/twitter-bootstrap-sass/mixins/_grid-framework.scss
>>
[09:50:26] column 245
[09:50:26] line 11
[09:50:26] file C:/svn/montblanc/LocalDistribution/sass/twitter-bootstrap-sass/mixins/_grid-framework.scss
[09:50:26] status 1
[09:50:26] messageFormatted LocalDistribution\sass\twitter-bootstrap-sass\mixins\_grid-framework.scss
Error: You may not @extend an outer selector from within @media.
   You may only @extend selectors within the same directive.
   From "@extend .col-md-6" on line 134 of LocalDistribution/sass/ItemDetails/_item-details.scss
    on line 11 of LocalDistribution/sass/twitter-bootstrap-sass/mixins/_grid-framework.scss
>>
[09:50:26] name Error
[09:50:26] stack Error: LocalDistribution\sass\twitter-bootstrap-sass\mixins\_grid-framework.scss
Error: You may not @extend an outer selector from within @media.
   You may only @extend selectors within the same directive.
   From "@extend .col-md-6" on line 134 of LocalDistribution/sass/ItemDetails/_item-details.scss
    on line 11 of LocalDistribution/sass/twitter-bootstrap-sass/mixins/_grid-framework.scss
>>
at options.error (C:\svn\montblanc\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:271:32)
[09:50:26] showStack false
[09:50:26] showProperties true
[09:50:26] plugin gulp-sass
[09:50:26] Finished 'sass' after 469 ms
[09:50:26] Starting 'font-awesome'...
[09:50:26] Starting 'clean-sass-tmp'...
[09:50:26] Finished 'clean-sass-tmp' after 20 µs

events.js:85
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
        ^
Error: Checksum error in glyf
```

Comment: I ran across this answer that is pretty good https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41773047/gulp-task-error-checksum-error-in-glyf